# Comparing two files in perl

Tags: arrays, perl, automation

I'm writing a Perl script where I need to compare two files.
For example :-

I've two arrays

```
@array  = {'1', '2',' 3', '5', '6'}
@array1 = {'1', '3', '7', '6'}
```

I want values of `@array` to look into `@array1` and if that value is present in 2nd array it should print match.

Output should look like this :

```
1,Match

3,Match

7,Not Match

6.Match
```

Comment: does the "diff" shell command do what you want?

Comment: With the code you have shown us, you produce a syntax error for `@array` and a one-element array that contains a hash reference for `@array1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the code maybe looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @array = ('1','2','3','5','6');
my @array2 = ('1', '3', '7', '6');

for my $item(@array2)
{
    if (grep($_ == $item, @array) > 0)
    {
         print "$item, Match\n";
    }
    else
    {
        print "$item, Not Match\n";
    }
}
```

Output

```
1, Match
3, Match
7, Not Match
6, Match
```

PS: reference from a comment by @simbabque

> The `@` sigil tells Perl that a variable is an array. The `()` is the list constructor, and in list context the list will be assigned to the array. `[]` constructs an array reference, which in list context will be treated as a one-element list and thus if you assign that to an array, you will end up with a one element array like `@foo = ( [ 1, 2, 3 ] )`. The OP is using `{}`, which constructs a hash reference, and works the same way, but since one of the two has an uneven number of elements, it will error out.

Comment: Neither `()` nor `[]` define an array. The `@` sigil tells Perl that a variable is an array. The `()` is the list constructor, and in _list context_ the list will be assigned to the array. `[]` constructs an _array reference_, which in list context will be treated as a one-element list and thus if you assign that to an array, you will end up with a one element array like `@foo = ( [ 1, 2, 3 ] )`. The OP is using `{}`, which constructs a hash reference, and works the same way, but since one of the two has an uneven number of elements, it will error out.

Comment: Your approach is fine, though, but for the wrong comparison operator. Since it's only numbers, use `==` and not `eq`. But you should always `use strict` and `use warnings` in all programs, especially when you write answers here for other people to find later. We want these people to learn things properly after all. :)

Comment: @simbabque you are right! thanks for your reply!

Comment: Feel free to [edit] your answer. You can use my comment in your answer if you want.